# A server-bound counter in PHP that would reset to zero every midnight or at least would seem so

Tags: php, counter

I'd like to know the best way to implement in PHP a counter that, having been incremented by some events on the server during a day, would be reset to zero with a new day coming, i.e at midnight. Probably comparing the date associated with the last value of the counter with the current date would make it reset?

EDIT: What if the counter gets reset the moment when it's going to be incremented provided that the code somehow figures out that the last time the counter was incremented was yesterday or a day earlier? It would be good enough.

Comment: Do you have `cron` available on said server?

Comment: What kind of counter would that be? Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, making an actual counter may not make the most sense. Achieving the same logic using other means may be better.

Comment: @prodigitalson Not sure, guess no.

Comment: @deceze Just a trivial integer counter going up by 1 with each relevant event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you storing your counter in a database? If so, you might just want to store the date of the last change along with it. Let me assume you have a table counters(name, value, date), then the following pseudo-code might give you an idea:

```
$counter_id='herpderp';
$today = date('dMY');
$date, $value = query("SELECT date, value FROM counters where name='$counter_id'");
if ($date!=$today) {
  $value = 0;
  query("UPDATE counters SET date='$today', value=1 WHERE name='$counter_id' AND date='$date'");
} else {
  query("UPDATE counters value=value+1 WHERE name='$counter_id' AND date='$date'");
}
echo $value;
```

Comment: Guess this is it, thanks. And to others: it really is a pseudo-code, don't take it literally.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server you're either going to either be able to implement a Scheduled Task (Windows) or CRON Job (Linux). This will be what allows your script to execute at a specific time of day (or night).

As for the counter, you can implement that in a few ways. For data integrity and security, I'd store the value in a database. To increment, fetch the value and increment it (there are also some ways, depending on your DBMS, to do this with a single SQL query). Otherwise you could always edit a configuration file with I/O commands in PHP.

**Setting up the CRON Job / Scheduled Task**

If you give me more information on your server configuration I can give you specific tutorials on where you can find out how to set up your task.

Once you've figured it out, you'll want to call a specific script. Your script in PHP can be set up as follows:

Compare the current D/M/Y to the previous days, most likely stored in your database or configuration file. If this checks out, update your database/file performing whatever analytic actions you deem fit.